# Does `copy.deepcopy` work with `NamedTuple`s in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, deep-copy

I see in the documentation that there's a `__deepcopy__` method that can be used to extend the behavior of `deepcopy` beyond the built-in types. However, the documentation for `NamedTuple` (the class version in the `typing` module) doesn't mention anything about it. But since it provides defaults for hashing and equality testing, I was wondering, does it provide a default for deep copying as well?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NamedTuple` doesn't define a special `__deepcopy__` handler, but it doesn't need to. `__deepcopy__` is only necessary to override/customize the default deep copying behavior (which just uses the `pickle` special methods, `__reduce_ex__` or `__reduce__`); for classes defined in Python (as opposed to C extension types), the default behavior is generally correct/complete. `object` itself provides useful default pickling behaviors for all non-extension types, assuming all their attributes are themselves picklable, e.g. no open file objects or the like.

Since `NamedTuple` is Python level, and has no special copying needs, it doesn't bother to implement a custom handler. You'd need to do so yourself only if some of the attributes of your `NamedTuple` are unpicklable and don't themselves define `__deepcopy__`.